# Kernel Panic Issue - not syncing VFS, unable to mount root fs - How do I resolve it?

Tags: ubuntu

I suddenly got a notification of my CPU usage being high, and when I check my website - it was down.

And, then tried to log in to FTP to deactivate WordPress plugins to see if it's an issue with WordPress (but couldn't access FTP/SSH as well)

Then I went to the dashboard and tried to access the console of Digital Ocean, and it displayed the following error in the image below:

http://prntscr.com/o1z7au

The last DO support response was to go to the recovery mode then:

-check filesystem
-mount disk image (or filesystem) (is it the same thing?)
(Refer to this: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/resources/recovery-iso/)

Then change the recovery mode to HDD and then power back on the droplet.

Maybe I misunderstood the official support response? Or did I miss something else?

I also tried restoring the droplet backup - that didn't work either. Do I have to fix the issue before trying to restore the backup?

I'm kinda in a panic mode - so please help me with a detailed response. I don't know how the hell did this problem occur in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

OK. You're clearly out of space. You're server started swapping madly, until your space allocation was exceeded. IMHO your hosting service should *never* have allowed you to be locked out. A service spinning out of control should be *killed* **before** you get locked out. So you can address the problem proper.

That said. I would recommend that you open up a service ticket with your provider. This doesn't look like a situation their "standard" tools accommodates. Like I said. The offending service should have been killed *before* you got locked out. Now it looks like you'll be unable to restart because you've exceeded your allocated space limit.

HTH